# cannot create new cocos2dx project using create_project.py

Tags: python, macos, cocos2d-x

I've installed cocos2dx in my mac and I am able to run a samplegame from the cocos2dx samples. Now I'm trying to create a new project using the `create_project.py`.

But I got this message in terminal

Trace back (most recent call last):

> File
>   "/Users/../cocos2d-x-2.2.1/tools/project-creator/create_project.py",
>   line 191, in 
>   shutil.copytree(context["src_project_path"], context["dst_project_path"], True)   File
>   "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py",
>   line 168, in copytree OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
>   '/Users/../../../template/multi-platform-cpp'

I've followed [this](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/How_to_create_a_multi-platform_project_in_one_command_line)
tutorial.

[This link](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/attachments/2790/create_project.py) will show you the script.

please help me with this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same problem and I used this command:

```
$ python create_project.py -project MyGame -package com.MyCompany.AwesomeGame -language cpp
```

instead of:

```
$ ./create_project.py -project PROJECT_NAME -package PACKAGE_NAME -language PROGRAMING_LANGUAGE
```

I created the project without problems.

I've followed [this](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/forums/6/topics/43031?r=43044#message-43044) tutorial.